# Paginate entries grouped by day

Tags: pagination

Been at this a couple of hours and my head is scrambled. Wonder if anyone has already solved it and cares to share? I'm trying to paginate a list of entries grouped by day - showing 3 days worth of entries on each page. This is slightly different (I think) to other threads on SE. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('stories').with(['categories']).all() %}
{% set allEntriesByDay = allEntries|group(e => e.postDate|date('long')) %}
{% for day, entriesInDay in allEntriesByDay %}
    <h2>{{ day }}</h2>
    {% for entry in entriesInDay %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% include "_includes/pagination" ignore missing %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this clever tweet](https://twitter.com/juban/status/1139207162159386625), you can do this:

```twig
{% set allEntriesByDay = craft
  .entries()
  .section('stories')
  .orderBy('postDate DESC')
  .with(['categories'])
  .all() | group(e => e.postDate|date('long')) %}

{% set dataProvider = create({
  'class': 'yii\\data\\ArrayDataProvider',
  'allModels': allEntriesByDay,
  'pagination': {'pageSize': 3}}) %} {# Set the days per page here #}

{% set results = dataProvider.getModels() %}

{% set currentPage = dataProvider.getPagination().getPage() + 1 %}
{% set totalPages = dataProvider.getPagination().getPageCount() %}

{% if currentPage > 1 %}
  {% set prevPage = currentPage - 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if currentPage < totalPages %}
  {% set nextPage = currentPage + 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% if results | length %}
  {% for day, entriesInDay in results %}
    <h2>{{ day }}</h2>
    {% for entry in entriesInDay %}
      {{ entry.title }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  <hr>
  <div>
  {% if prevPage is defined %}
    <a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.absoluteUrl, {'q': craft.app.request.get('q'), 'page': prevPage}) }}">< Previous page</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% if nextPage is defined %}
    <a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.absoluteUrl, {'q': craft.app.request.get('q'), 'page': nextPage}) }}"> - Next page ></a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks Oli.

Comment: I can't take the credit for this but thanks!