# Order entries by related "Year" category and paginate?

Tags: categories, pagination, group

I have a section called `Library`, and a category group called `libraryYears`. The categories in that group are just years (`2021`, `2020`, `2019`...)

Each entry in the Library is related to a year in the `libraryYears` via a related Entries field called `theYear`.

I want to list all Library entries in order of the related year, so 2021 entries first, followed by 2020 entries, and so on. I don't need year headings, I just need them to be in order of year. But I also want to paginate them so there are only 10 per page.

I tried toying around with the `group` filter, but can't get it going with pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of thing, I don't see much advantage of using a category relationship for the years (unless each category actually has further meta data or content held against it)  - I'd probably just use a normal number field and get the editors to type in the year (or select from a pre-made dropdown if the range is reasonable)... But that doesn't help you much for your current situation.

How about using the Preparse plugin to populate a hidden field with the year from the chosen category on save? Then you can use a regular `orderBy()` parameter, which in turn will work with Craft's native pagination.

Alternatively you could use the `group` filter and then manually build some pagination functionality using segment logic, routes, and `offset` (or perhaps `slice`)... but that sounds like a really complex pain... I wouldn't even attempt that to be honest.

Comment: You know I think you're right that I should just convert these categories to a select field. I've imported them using FeedMe from an XML feed, so it shouldn't be too hard to pull in the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort using the `multisort` filter ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#multisort)) then paginate using [Yii's ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider) - [see this post for reference](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33882/paginate-entries-grouped-by-day/33885).

```twig
{# Fetch your entries and order by theYear descending #}
{% set allEntriesByYear = craft.entries()
    .section('library')
    .orderBy('postDate DESC')
    .theYear(':notempty:')
    .with(['theYear'])
    .all() | multisort(e => e.theYear[0], direction=SORT_DESC) %}

{# Create your custom pagination #}
{% set dataProvider = create({
    'class': 'yii\\data\\ArrayDataProvider',
    'allModels': allEntriesByYear,
    'pagination': {'pageSize': 4}}) %} {# Change this to the number you need per page #}

{% set results = dataProvider.getModels() %}

{% set currentPage = dataProvider.getPagination().getPage() + 1 %}
{% set totalPages = dataProvider.getPagination().getPageCount() %}

{% if currentPage > 1 %}
    {% set prevPage = currentPage - 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if currentPage < totalPages %}
    {% set nextPage = currentPage + 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% if results | length %}
    {% for entry in results %}
        {{ entry.title }} - {{ entry.theYear[0] }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<hr>
<div>
    {% if prevPage is defined %}
        <a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.absoluteUrl, {'q': craft.app.request.get('q'), 'page': prevPage}) }}">< Previous page</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if nextPage is defined %}
        <a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.absoluteUrl, {'q': craft.app.request.get('q'), 'page': nextPage}) }}"> - Next page ></a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Getting into Yii stuff is a little more than I wanted to do but this is a great suggestion.

Comment: Ah, fair enough :)

Comment: This is really neat, being able to invoke the pagination functionality on an arbitrary array without a huge mass of complicated offsets/slicing. Will probably need this one day.